# Responsive menu using trunk js how to make drawer to open right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

hey plz check this [responsive menu](http://www.roblukedesign.com/trunk/Trunk-Package/trunk.html/) i want to make the drawer to move right side but i have no idea about css animation can anyone suggest me what to do.
here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wH4P/)

i try to make the translate3d -240px the drawers move right but navigation is disappear.

```
header.open,
.content.open 
{   
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(240px,0,0);
    -webkit-animation: open .5s ease-in-out;

    -moz-transform: translate3d(240px,0,0);
    -moz-animation: open .5s ease-in-out;

    transform: translate3d(240px,0,0);
    animation: open .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this as well and made the necessary tweaks and now it works. Some of the changes below but check the fiddle for working code: http://jsfiddle.net/pkxtj9z1/

```
.burger {
    float: right;
    right: 10px;
}

nav {
    right: 5px;
}

nav li {
    text-align: right;
}

header.open,
.content.open 
{   
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-240px,0,0);
    -webkit-animation: open .5s ease-in-out;

    -moz-transform: translate3d(-240px,0,0);
    -moz-animation: open .5s ease-in-out;

    transform: translate3d(-240px,0,0);
    animation: open .5s ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes open {
    0%      {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
    70%    {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-260px,0,0);}
    100%  {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-240px,0,0);}
}
@-moz-keyframes open {
    0%      {-moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
    70%    {-moz-transform: translate3d(-260px,0,0);}
    100%  {-moz-transform: translate3d(-240px,0,0);}
}
@keyframes open {
    0%      {transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
    70%    {transform: translate3d(-260px,0,0);}
    100%  {transform: translate3d(-240px,0,0);}
}
```